# What does a Lagrangian of the form $L=m^2\dot x^4 +U(x)\dot x^2 -W(x)$ represent?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism

I saw this Lagrangian in notes I have printed:

$$
L\left(x,\frac{dx}{dt}\right) = \frac{m^2}{12}\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^4 + m\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2\times V(x) -V^2(x).
$$
(It appears in the exercises in the first chapter of Goldstein.)

What is it? Is it even physical? It seems like it doesn't have the right units of energy.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Lagrangian:

$$L~=~\frac{1}{3}T^2+2TV-V^2,  \qquad T~:=~\frac{m}{2}\dot{x}^2. $$

Lagrange equation:

$$2(T-V)V^{\prime}~=~\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}
~=~ \frac{d}{dt} \left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}}\right)
~=~ \frac{d}{dt} \left[\left(\frac{2}{3}T +2V\right)m\dot{x}\right] $$
$$~=~  \left(\frac{2}{3}T +2V\right)m\ddot{x}
+ \left(\frac{2}{3}m\dot{x}\ddot{x} +2V^{\prime}\dot{x}\right)m\dot{x} 
~=~  2(T+V)m\ddot{x} +4TV^{\prime}, $$
or,

$$- 2(T+V)V^{\prime}~=~ 2(T+V)m\ddot{x}. $$

In other words, one gets Newton's second law$^1$

$$ m\ddot{x}~=~-V^{\prime}. \qquad\qquad\qquad(N2) $$

So the Lagrangian $L$ is equivalent to the usual $T-V$ at the classical level.

--

$^1$ One may wonder about the second branch $T+V=0$, but since $T+V={\rm const}$ is a first integral to (N2), the second branch is already included in the first branch (N2).