# What is the physical interpretation of a Lagrangian with $\dot{x}^4$?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, energy-conservation

Among the exercises in the first chapter of Goldstein's book "Classical Mechanics", it appears the lagrangian
$$
L\left(x,\frac{dx}{dt}\right) = \frac{m^2}{12}\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^4 + m\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2\times V(x) -V^2(x).
$$

For a related answer, and the solution of the Euler-Lagrange equation see [What does a Lagrangian of the form $L=m^2\dot x^4 +U(x)\dot x^2 -W(x)$ represent?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17406/)

Apart from its solution, my question is: does this Lagrangian correspond to a real physical system, or is it just a mathematical construction? Is the fact that one recovers Newton's second law a coincidence? (see link above for the derivation)

Moreover, assume a more general Lagrangian of the form $L = \alpha \left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^4 + \beta \left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 -V^2(x) $, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are just constants. Are there general considerations (e.g. about energy conservation, etc.) that can be made?

Comment: Comments to the post (v2): 1. Note that OP's "more general Lagrangian" does strictly speaking not include Goldstein's example. 2. FWIW, the Lagrangian energy function is conserved as long as the Lagrangian doesn't have explicit time dependence.