# Is it always the case that the square root of a lagrangian gives the same equations of motion as the lagrangian itself?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle

Inspired by the Phys.SE post [Geodesic Equation from variation: Is the squared lagrangian equivalent?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149082/2451) I was wondering if it is always the case that the square root of a lagrangian gives the same equations of motion as the lagrangian itself? Are there specific counterexamples, or is there any way to derive a set of conditions the lagrangian has to satisfy, for it to have this particular property?

Comment: Are you talking about the Lagrangian formalism for particles or for fields?

Comment: particles. Sorry, should have clarified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is rarely$^1$ the case. Sufficient conditions and examples are given in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2506272/11127) duplicate Math.SE post.

--

$^1$ An instructive example is perhaps [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17406/2451) Phys.SE post: The coefficients of each squared term in the Lagrangian have been carefully fine-tuned to make it work. It is not just $(T-V)^2$.