# Damped harmonic Oscillator Lagrangian equivalence

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, friction, harmonic-oscillator, dissipation

The objective is to prove that the Lagrangian:
$$L'=\frac{2\dot x+\lambda x}{2\Omega x}\tan^{-1}(\frac{2\dot x+\lambda x}{2\Omega x})-\frac{1}{2}\ln(\dot x^2+\lambda \dot{x } x + \omega^2x^2), \qquad \Omega=\sqrt{\omega^2-\lambda^2/4},$$
is equivalent to the lagrangian of the damped harmonic oscillator:
$$L=e^{\lambda t}(\frac{m}{2}\dot x^2 -\frac{m\omega^2}{2}x^2), $$
but I dont know how to show that there is a time derivative of a function that differs from one Lagrangian to the other;

(It's exercise 2.14 from Nivaldo Lemos, *Analytical Mechanics,* 2018.)

Comment: Since you only have one Lagrangian in the current version of your question it's difficult to show it differs from a second one.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. Two Lagrangians, whose difference is not a total derivative, can still yield the same EOM, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/131925/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17406/2451) Phys.SE posts.
2. Check that both Lagrangians lead to the same EOM $\ddot{x}+\lambda \dot{x}+\omega^2x~=~0$ of the damped harmonic oscillator.