# Can these different Lagrangians lead to the same equation of motions?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism

[image]A particle of mass $m$ moves in one-dimension with position $x$ and potential $V(x)$, described by the Lagrangian $$ L = \frac{1}{12}m^2 \dot{x}^4 + m \dot{x}^2 V - V^2  $$ Show that the resulting equation of motion is identical to that arising from the usual Lagrangian  $ L = \frac{1}{2}m \dot{x}^2 -V .$

Comment: Hi physicsLover! On Stack Exchange, we tend not to answer highly specific, 'homework style' questions. Try to *show your own attempts to solve the problem*, and potentially rephrase the question to be more open ended - such as, "What makes two Lagrangians yield the same equations of motion"?

Comment: @physicsLover What have you tried to solve the problem?

Comment: I have computed the derivatives of L with respect to x and x_dot and put them in the Lagrangian equation to find out the equation of motion. I have attached a pic for reference.

Comment: Please make sure all equations are written as part of the post rather than uploaded as an image. We appreciate that transcribing may be tedious, but it helps to make a better post for the site.

Comment: All the equations are written in the question. The image is for showing my attempts to solve the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17406/2451

Comment: To me more interesting would be what is the Hamiltonian, is it also equivalent

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a minus sign missing at the end ($-(-V)=V$) and when taking the total derivative with respect to $t$ you forgot that the potential also depends on $t$: $V(x(t))$. Here is my solution:

Applying the Euler-Lagrange-Equations (1) to the first Lagrangian we get (assuming $V=V(x(t))$):
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}=-2V\partial_xV+m\dot x^2 \partial_x V\\ \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot x}=\frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{1}{3}m^2\dot x^3+2m\dot xV\right]=m^2\dot x^2\ddot x+2m\ddot xV+2m\dot x^2\partial_x V,\\ \frac{\partial L}{\partial x}\stackrel{(1)}{=}\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot x}\Leftrightarrow -\partial_xV(2V-m\dot x^2+2m\dot x^2)=m\ddot x(m\dot x^2+2V),$$ Assuming kinetik Energy $\frac{1}{2}m\dot x^2$ is not equal to the potential Energy $V$ (else $L=0$ thus E-L-Eq. (1) yields a trivial solution with no information) $$\Leftrightarrow -\partial_xV=m\ddot x.$$ Which is the same result as the one that you get applying the Euler-Lagrange-Equation to the second "usual" Lagrangian.

Comment: Thank you. But I could not follow why is V = V(x(t)) ? As the particle is in motion, its position x is a function of time t i.e x = x(t). But this does not imply V = V(x) = V(x(t)), since potential is a function dependent on the spatial position only.

Comment: yes, but the spacial position, on which the potential depends, varies with time!

Comment: @physicsLover is everything clear now?

Comment: Not clear actually. For example, along the x-axis let there be a potential V  whose value at a point depends only on the distance of the point from the origin, V = V(x). Now if a particle under this potential executes 1-d motion along the axis, then its positions x changes with time x = x(t). But does this time dependence of particle's position make V(x) = V(x(t)) ?

Comment: @physicsLover Yes!!! I'm not sure what to add to what you have said. Its all there. The Potential OF THE PARTICLE depends on the position OF THE PARTICLE, which varies with time. The downvote I got was due to responding to a "do-my-homework-question" before you showed what you had tried.

Comment: Oh, yes... I am convinced at last. Thanks a lot for helping me (and sorry for the downvote you get, I should have upload my attempt first).